# which language is used for developing this site?

Tags: php, programming-languages

http://www.samsclub.mobi/products?cid=2043

Is it possible to find out the technology used in developing the site. I feel it could be php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's PHP:

http://www.samsclub.mobi/products?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42

If you are curious why this GUID causes that image to be displayed, see http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php

Answer (score 8):

Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.14

Comment: By looking at the HTTP headers.

Comment: Yes, with catching HTTP headers.

Comment: Are disclosing such details compulsory?

Answer (score 4):

It's PHP - http://www.samsclub.mobi/index.php

Answer (score 3):

It is PHP. But even within PHP, you still don't know whether it's using a framework or library, or what PHP extensions it has installed. Nor do you know what database they're using.

Finding out that it's written in PHP really doesn't tell you very much that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

May be PHP
http://www.wmtips.com/tools/info/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.samsclub.mobi%2Fproducts%3Fcid%3D2043

Answer (score 0):

It is PHP!
There are calls to scripts in the source code reffering to php-scripts:

```
_mnubtn.php?w=220&amp;h=34&amp;t=Automotive
```